# RootProject and ProjectRef

Tags: sbt

I have been trying to find more information on RootProject and ProjectRef, but looks like it is not mentioned at all in sbt documentation.

I understand that if you are referencing a root project you should use RootProject and ProjectRef when you are referencing a sub-project. However it is not clear how the behavior will be different between them. Can somebody please help explain?

Also the fact that it is not documented, does it mean that RootProject and ProjectRef are not the recommended way to reference other sbt projects?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?  That is, why are you referencing another project and what kind of project is being referenced?  (It isn't bad to want to do so- just looing for context.)

Comment: Sure, Mark. I have a project that contains all my DAO classes and handles database operations. This DAO project needs a reference to all the domain classes in the Domain Project. At the same time, I also have a service project that references both.

Comment: So, you want the DAO project to depend on the Domain Project?  As in http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#classpath-dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to define the dependency. The example there has the project structure hello, hello/foo, and hello/bar. The Build.scala shown is in hello, so it can reference the hello/foo and hello/bar using Project(...). However, for the Build.scala in hello/foo that depends on hello/bar, then you cannot use Project(file("../bar")...), as sbt will throw error. The only way to reference that is to use either RootProject(file("../bar")...) or ProjectRef(file("../bar")...) Afterwards, then of course it is just a simple dependsOn(bar) statement. Which to use(ProjectRef, RootProject)?

Comment: Can you update the question with these additional details?  It helps future readers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

A single sbt build has a single `project/` directory for `.scala` build definitions and plugin definitions.  There can be multiple subprojects within that build with their own `.sbt` files, but not their own `project/*.scala` files.

When you want to include other, separate builds directly instead of using their published binaries, you use "source dependencies".  This is what `RootProject` and `ProjectRef` declare.  `ProjectRef` is the most general: you specify the location of the build (a URI) and the ID of the project in the build (a String) that you want to depend on.  `RootProject` is a convenience that selects the root project for the build at the URI you specify.

Source dependencies do have an overhead: startup time, memory usage, and command line usability.  If the group of projects don't need to be separate, it is best to use a single build with standard subprojects.

Comment: Mark, can you expand on why source dependencies have more overhead? I'm curious how much overhead we can expect them to add. What types of issues arise with command line usability?

Comment: Well, in the case of source dependencies SBT has to run recursively against the source project's build instead of pulling in JARs.