# How to share version values between project/plugins.sbt and project/Build.scala?

Tags: sbt

I would like to share a common version variable between an sbtPlugin and the rest of the build

Here is what I am trying:

in `project/Build.scala`:

```
object Versions {
  scalaJs = "0.5.0-M3"
}
object MyBuild extends Build {
  //Use version number
}
```

in `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" % "scalajs-sbt-plugin" % Versions.scalaJs)
```

results in

```
plugins.sbt:15: error: not found: value Versions
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" % "scalajs-sbt-plugin" % Versions.scalaJs)
```

Is there a way to share the version number specification between `plugins.sbt` and the rest of the build, e.g. `project/Build.scala`?

Comment: Could the OP comment on why the answer that received the bounty isn't the accepted answer? Was it purely a matter of timing?

Comment: To be honest I can't remember. It may have been a timing thing as you suggest but it's been a couple years at this point, and the use case I had (sharing a ScalaJS version between both) isn't something I have to do anymore. Sorry I know that's probably not a very satisfying response but it's the only honest one I can offer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### sbt-buildinfo

If you need to share `version` number between `build.sbt` and `hello.scala`, what would you normally do? I don't know about you, but I would use [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) that I wrote.

This can be configured using `buildInfoKeys` setting to expose arbitrary key values like `version` or some custom `String` value. I understand this is not exactly what you're asking but bear with me.

### meta-build (turtles all the way down)

As [Jacek noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944311/3827) and stated in [Getting Started Guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Full-Def.html), the build in sbt is a project defined in the build located in `project` directory one level down. To distinguish the builds, let's define the normal build as the *proper build*, and the build that defines the proper build as *meta-build*. For example, we can say that an sbt plugin is a library of the root project in the meta build.

Now let's get back to your question. How can we share info between `project/Build.scala` and `project/plugins.sbt`?

### using sbt-buildinfo for meta-build

We can just define another level of build by creating `project/project` and add `sbt-buildinfo` to the (meta-)meta-build.

Here are the files.

In `project/project/buildinfo.sbt`:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.3.2")
```

In `project/project/Dependencies.scala`:

```scala
package metabuild

object Dependencies {
  def scalaJsVersion = "0.5.0-M2"
}
```

In `project/build.properties`:

```scala
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

In `project/buildinfo.sbt`:

```scala
import metabuild.Dependencies._

buildInfoSettings

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo

buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey]("scalaJsVersion" -> scalaJsVersion)

buildInfoPackage := "metabuild"
```

In `project/scalajs.sbt`:

```scala
import metabuild.Dependencies._

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" % "scalajs-sbt-plugin" % scalaJsVersion)
```

In `project/Build.scala`:

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._
import metabuild.BuildInfo._

object Builds extends Build {
  println(s"test: $scalaJsVersion")
}
```

So there's a bit of a boilerplate in `project/buildinfo.sbt`, but the version info is shared across the build definition and the plugin declaration.

If you're curious where `BuildInfo` is defined, peek into `project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/src_managed/`.

Comment: Did I get it correctly that without source generation `metabuild.Dependencies` won't be visible in `Build.scala` ?

Comment: For sbt 1.x, replace `buildInfoSettings; sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo` with `enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)`

Comment: `> I don't know about you, but I would`
What a strange way of starting an answer 

Answer (score 3):

For the `project/plugins.sbt` file you'd have to have another `project` under `project` with the `Versions.scala` file. That would make the definition of `Versions.scalaJs` visible.

The reason for doing it is that `*.sbt` files belong to a project build definition at the current level with `*.scala` files under `project` to expand on it. And it's...[turtles all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down), i.e. [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive).

I'm not sure how much the following can help, but it might be worth to try out - to share versions between projects - `plugins` and the main one - you'd have to use `ProjectRef` as described in the answer to [RootProject and ProjectRef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19469708/1305344):

> When you want to include other, separate builds directly instead of
>   using their published binaries, you use "source dependencies". This is
>   what `RootProject` and `ProjectRef` declare. `ProjectRef` is the most
>   general: you specify the location of the build (a URI) and the ID of
>   the project in the build (a String) that you want to depend on. 
>   `RootProject` is a convenience that selects the root project for the
>   build at the URI you specify.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is to hack. For example, in `build.sbt` you can add a task:

```
val readPluginSbt = taskKey[String]("Read plugins.sbt file.")

readPluginSbt := {
        val lineIterator = scala.io.Source.fromFile(new java.io.File("project","plugins.sbt")).getLines
            val linesWithValIterator = lineIterator.filter(line => line.contains("scalaxbVersion"))
            val versionString =  linesWithValIterator.mkString("\n").split("=")(1).trim
            val version = versionString.split("\n")(0) // only val declaration
        println(version)
        version
    }
```

When you call `readPluginSbt` you will see the contents of `plugins.sbt`. You can parse this file and extract the variable.

For example:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")

val scalaxbVersion = "1.1.2"

addSbtPlugin("org.scalaxb" % "sbt-scalaxb" % scalaxbVersion)

addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-pack" % "0.5.1")
```

You can extract `scalaxbVersion` with regular expressions/split:

```
scala> val line = """val scalaxbVersion = "1.1.2""""
line: String = val scalaxbVersion = "1.1.2"

scala>  line.split("=")(1).trim
res1: String = "1.1.2"
```