# How to enable compiler plugin from libraryDependencies?

Tags: sbt

I have a compiler plugin in library dependencies and would like to enable it. Something like

```
autoCompilerPlugins := true

libraryDependencies += compilerPlugin(update.value.allModules.find(_.name contains "continuations-plugin").get)

scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"
```

gives

```
/Users/luc/scala/release-sanity-check/build.sbt:20: error: A setting cannot depend on a task
libraryDependencies += compilerPlugin(update.value.allModules.find(_.name contains "continuations-plugin").get)
                                  ^
```

Can I do it with a custom task?

```
val addContinuationsPlugin = taskKey[Unit]("Add continuations plugin")

addContinuationsPlugin := {
  val plugin = update.value.allModules.find(_.name contains "continuations-plugin")
  // add plugin?
}
```

Repository in question: https://github.com/scala/scala-dist-smoketest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this (see [sbt API](http://www.scala-sbt.org/documentation.html))

```
scalacOptions ++= {
  val compileConfig = update.value.configurations.find(_.configuration == "compile").get
  val pluginModule = compileConfig.modules.find(_.module.name contains "continuations-plugin").get
  val pluginFile = pluginModule.artifacts.head._2
  Seq(s"-Xplugin:${pluginFile.getCanonicalPath}", "-P:continuations:enable")
}
```

The compilePlugin method is designed to ease the task when you are using Ivy to resolve the plugins, and you can do so correctly.

Option #2 is to try to ensure their is a transitive `compiler-plugin->compiler-plugin` configuration dependency chain between your project and the project where you discover the continuations plugin (where eventually there will be a `compiler-plugin->default(compile)` link).  However, without seeing your dependency tree, I can't advice around option #2 (which is the more robust method).

Comment: Thank you! https://github.com/scala/scala-dist-smoketest/commit/b4a342a26883d7e10cc7a28918d30b664e23f466

Answer (score 2):

This is quite tricky, and I don't know if I could recommend using this technique beyond smoke testing by Typesafe, but here it goes. (Don't try this at home.)

As you and Jacek noted, `libraryDependencies` as well as the version of the plugin must be known statically at the compile-time of the build. However, since the build can be built using a meta-build, we can think of it as runtime of the metabuild. I've demonstrated that in my answer to [How to share version values between project/plugins.sbt and project/Build.scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103453/3827)

So using sbt-buildinfo, we can lift task values of the meta-build into a setting value of the proper build. The next question is how we can go about finding out the version of the continuation plugin in the meta-build. Again, this is a gimmicky trick, but we can make a bogus Ivy configuration within the meta-build, add scala-dist in there, and fish out the version number from `externalDependencyClasspath in BogusConfig`.  The change is sent in as [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103453/3827) too.

#### project/project/buildinfo.sbt

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.3.2")
```

#### project/project/Dependencies.scala

```scala
package metabuild

import sbt._

object Dependencies {
  def scalaDistVersion = sys.props("project.version")
}

object Configs {
  lazy val BogusConfig = config("bogus")
}
```

#### project/plugins.sbt

```scala
import metabuild.Dependencies._
import metabuild.Configs._

lazy val continuationPluginVersion = taskKey[String]("version of the continuation plugin")

lazy val build = (project in file(".")).
  configs(BogusConfig).
  settings(inConfig(BogusConfig)(Defaults.configSettings): _*).
  settings(buildInfoSettings: _*).
  settings(addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.6.4"): _*).
  settings(
    resolvers += "jgit-repo" at "http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-dist" % scalaDistVersion % BogusConfig,
    sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo,
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](
      "scalaDistVersion" -> scalaDistVersion,
      continuationPluginVersion
    ),
    buildInfoPackage := "metabuild",
    continuationPluginVersion := {
        val bogusClasspath = (externalDependencyClasspath in BogusConfig).value
        val f = (bogusClasspath find { _.data.getName contains "continuations-plugin" }).get.data
        f.getName.replaceAllLiterally("scala-continuations-plugin_" + scalaDistVersion + "-", "").replaceAllLiterally(".jar", "")
    }
  )
```

#### build.sbt

```scala
import metabuild.BuildInfo._

// versionWithGit

version := scalaDistVersion

scalaVersion := version.value

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-dist" % version.value

autoCompilerPlugins := true

libraryDependencies +=
  compilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % ("scala-continuations-plugin_" + version.value) % continuationPluginVersion)

scalacOptions += "-P:continuations:enable"
```

Comment: Thanks! I went for jsuereth's solution in the end, that was a smaller sledgehammer.

Answer (score 1):

*"I have a compiler plugin in library dependencies and would like to add enable it."*

Following [Compiler Plugin Support](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Compiler-Plugins.html) from the sbt official documentation you should enable support for compiler plugins in `build.sbt` as follows:

```
autoCompilerPlugins := true
```

You then use `addCompilerPlugin` to add the plugin as a dependency (to `libraryDependencies`) in `plugin->default(compile)` scope.

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-tools.sxr" %% "sxr" % "0.3.0")
```

With the settings you can set up the plugin:

```
scalacOptions :=
    scalacOptions.value :+ ("-Psxr:base-directory:" + (scalaSource in Compile).value.getAbsolutePath)
```

Comment: The point of my question is that the argument to `addCompilerPlugin` depends on the `libraryDependencies`. The version of the plugin is not known statically.

Comment: Who's computing libraryDependencies? It has to be known at build time (when the settings are computed) or sbt won't load the project. Settings are immutable and the only way to change their values is to `reload` the project that boils down to knowing their values at build time. Do you have a project on GitHub to demo the use case?

Comment: The build file: https://github.com/scala/scala-dist-smoketest/blob/2.11.x/build.sbt. scala-dist is a big pom that depends on a specific scala compiler / library, and also the matching continuations library.

Comment: Settings like `libraryDependencies` can depend on other settings, even ourselves. The solution is to check `libraryDependencies` for required libraries and execute `addCompilerPlugin` for successful match. Don't touch `update` as it's too late (it's done at runtime and is a task). As a matter of fact, there's the document that describes it - http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Compiler-Plugins.html#version-specific-compiler-plugin-example.