# How to obtain the value of scalacOptions for the meta-project in a plugin?

Tags: sbt

In the `ensime-sbt` plugin, we need to be able to obtain the compiler flags that the sbt process is using to compile the build definition (i.e. everything under `project`).

We have the `State` object, but I can't see any way to get the compiler flags, where are they?

Note: this is **not** the compile flags for the projects themselves, I mean only for the build definition.

e.g. say the project has this in the `project/plugins.sbt`

```
scalacOptions += "-Xfuture"
```

how can we read that from the plugin?

This is somewhat related to [How to share version values between project/plugins.sbt and project/Build.scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944108/)

Comment: You know about `reload plugins` that lets you in to the meta-project build? While in there, you can query for settings, i.e. `show scalacOptions`. Perhaps you could execute commands using `State` that would correspond to `reload plugins; show scalacOptions`. Dunno how to do it in a plugin :(

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a build file for the project. And, to do that, you have to add the plugin in both the meta-project and the meta-project for the meta-project.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    val scalacOptions4Meta = SettingKey[Seq[String]]("scalacOptions4Meta")
    val mygenerator = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("mygenerator")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    mygenerator := {
      val file = sourceManaged.value / "settings4Meta.scala"
      val opts = (scalacOptions in Compile).value
        .map(opt => "\"" + opt + "\"")
      val content = s"""
        import sbt._
        import Keys._

        object MyBuild extends Build {
          lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
            .settings(
              MyPlugin.autoImport.scalacOptions4Meta := Seq(${opts.mkString(",")})
            )
        }"""
      IO.write(file, content)
      Seq(file)
    }
  )
}
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("myplugin" % "myplugin" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT")

scalacOptions := Seq("-Xfuture")

sourceGenerators in Compile += mygenerator.taskValue
```

project/project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("myplugin" % "myplugin" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT")
```

Comment: that's a bit nasty, I'm not keen on that at all as it would impact all users of ENSIME. I'd actually rather do some JVM reflective magic to go and find the flags from the meta-project's classpath.