# Is it possible for a Scala project to list its own dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

In sbt, we define dependencies for a project:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.beachape" %% "enumeratum" % "1.3.2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
)
```

Is it possible for the Scala application thus compiled to get access to this data, somehow?

I am making a modular system of Play 2.4 APIs and would like the "umbrella" to be able to list which APIs it's carrying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will probably get this done using [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) that I found via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944108/how-to-share-version-values-between-project-plugins-sbt-and-project-build-scala).

Other suggestions are of course welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is checking maven repositories. For example, the link below shows all libraries **com.beachape" %% "enumeratum" % "1.3.2"** depends on.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beachape/enumeratum_2.11/1.3.2

Comment: I meant that the project would programmatically be able to know its sbt side metainfo, such as libraryDepencendies. For manually seeing dependencies I use sbt dependencyTree https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph