# project/Dependencies.scala not accessible from plugins.sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm unable to reference the object Dependencies from within `plugins.sbt` on compile getting the error `error: not found: value Dependencies`

```
/project/plugins.sbt
/project/Dependencies.sbt
```

`Depencies.scala` is just a collection of objects

```
object Dependencies { 
  object Play {
    ...
    val sbtPlugin = "..." 
...
```

Similarly I use it in `./build.sbt` to add `libraryDependencies` without problems:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(libraryDependencies += Seq(
    Dependencies.Play.dependencies, ...
```

Thanks for any ideas, I'm curious more than anything why `build.sbt` can access `project` folder resources

Answer (score 4):

If you want a dependencies files to be accessible from `project/plugins.sbt` then you need to put it into `project/project/Dependencies.scala`.

(I'm assuming your file is called `Dependencies.scala`, not `Dependencies.sbt` or `Depencies.scala` as shown in your question.)

In general `somedir/*.sbt` files can access `.scala` files in `somedir/project/*.scala`.

Comment: @RichDougherty but then `/project/project/Dependencies` is not accessible in `build.sbt`

Comment: @PavelVoronin it's not supposed to be: they are on different levels: 0-level `./`, 1-level `project/`, 2-level `project/project/`, etc. So `*.scala` files from (n+1)-level are visible in the `*.sbt` files of the n-level.

Comment: @laughedelic Yes. And it is not a [trivial task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944108/how-to-share-version-values-between-project-plugins-sbt-and-project-build-scala/) to share data between them.